# Populating A Kendo UI Grid With A JSON String

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo UI Grid and can't get it to show data when using a JSON string. [I created a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Halcyon/DnhSG/) What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#grid').kendoGrid(
        {
            scrollable: false,
            data: '{"TestHeader":"This is some test data"}',
            columns: [ { field: 'TestHeader' } ]
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be closer to what you want (note the changes to the data definition):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#grid').kendoGrid(
    {
        scrollable: false,
        dataSource: { data: [ { "TestHeader": "This is some test data"} ] },
        columns: [ { field: 'TestHeader' } ]
    });
});​
```

Comment: @Halcyon no sweat. P.S. the Fiddle helped in figuring out the issue; kudos for including it in the question!